# Log4net with Entity Framework 5 and MVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, log4net

So I am starting this new project and want to use Log4net to log to the Database. I am using EF for other things and it connects fine. For some reason L4N is not logging anything but not throwing any errors. Just wondering what step(s) I may be missing, hope someone can point it out. Do I need to "save" to the db somehow? Thanx so much in advance.

My web.config:

```
<log4net> 
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="100" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.EntityClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=myserver;initial catalog=Reporting;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=myid;Password=mypassword" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO [myschema].[Log] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="Info" />
  <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

and my controller:

```
 ...
 using log4net;
 using System.Reflection;

namespace MyNames.Controllers
{
  public class ClientController : Controller
  {    
     ReportingEntities db = new ReportingEntities();
     private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

     public ActionResult Index()
     {  
         this.log.Debug("Sample message to log to Db");
         return View();
     }
   }
 }
```

EDIT: So I made the mods suggested gorilly but still doesnt work. Just happened to check output window and even though I enabled debugging it still shows this
 .[image]. 
Tried the debugging suggestion from [here](http://dotnetforyou.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/debugging-log4net-when-it-stops-logging/) but no error was thrown.

From my log4net internal debugging file:

```
log4net: Assembly [DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246] Loaded From [C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\bf082a83\4eb20e9a\assembly\dl3\c62a3103\e01aa9f6_fda1cf01\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll]
log4net: Assembly [DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [DotNetOpenAuth.Core, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2780ccd10d57b246] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Shutdown called on Hierarchy [log4net-default-repository]
```

Comment: After moving my log4net to a separate config file per SO question #8306548, I finally get an error: "log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Failed to load connection type [System.Data.EntityClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]"

Comment: Continual troubleshooting eventually lead to permissions not being set on the table in the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to Global.asax.cs (in Application_Start()):

`log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

Also, you can turn on log4net debugging to help you figure out what's going wrong by adding this line to your Web.config under `<appSettings>`:

**Edit:** The below had `value="false"`, but should be `value="true"`.

```
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

**Edit:**

You can send log4net's internal debug logging to a file by adding the following to your Web.config (see the official explanation [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug)):

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
            name="textWriterTraceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="C:\mylogdirectory\log4net_debug.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Thanx for the response, but no dice. When I switch the appender to '<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>' it doesnt log to the event viewer either. :-(

Comment: You will probably find the cause fairly quickly if you get the log4net internal debug logging working. I edited my answer to include information regarding the setup of log4net internal debugging.

Comment: Also, I failed at cut/paste...the line in `<appSettings>` should be:

`<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>`,

not

`<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="false"/>`. This explains why you didn't see any log4net debugging output. Just change that value from `false` to `true`, and it should give you some insight.

Comment: @user116923, have you had a chance to try this again with `<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>`?

Comment: Thanx. I actually figured it was a typo and was setting it to "true". OTOH - Your suggestions helped me tweak a few things, like SO question #8940026, but havent fixed it yet. I added the log entry from the debug file that looks interesting. Everything else seems normal, just isnt logging.

Comment: There was a gazillion other issues, but w/o your help I wouldnt have been able to determine what they were, so in my opinion this is the correct answer. Thanx!